# Visual Studio 2010 assembler listing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly

I use VS2010 to generate an assembler listing. Than I create a new project, add generated *.asm file and try to compile it. During the compillation I receive some erros like:

```
main.asm(54): error A2008: syntax error : lambda0
```

at this line of generated asm:

```
PUBLIC  ??R<lambda0>@?A0x1262112e@@QBE_NH@Z     ; `anonymous namespace'::<lambda0>::operator()
```

Another one is:

```
main.asm(72): error A2039: line too long
```

The length of 72th line is 538 symbols.

Looks like Visual Studio generates an incompatible asm code for examle for lambda expressions.

The next C++ code I used for test:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cctype>

 std::string LTrimString(std::string s)
 {
      s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int ch) {                     return !std::isspace((unsigned char)ch); }));
      return s;
 }

 std::string RTrimString(std::string s)
 {
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int ch) { return !std::isspace((unsigned char)ch); }).base(), s.end());
    return s;
 }

 std::string TrimString(std::string s)
 {
    return LTrimString(RTrimString(s));
 }

 bool StartsWith(std::string full_str, std::string start_str)
 {
    return full_str.substr(0, start_str.length()) == start_str;
 }

 int main()
 {
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
     while(ifs)
     {
         std::string line;
         std::getline(ifs, line);

        if(StartsWith(TrimString(line), ">>>"))
            std::cout << "###";

         std::cout << line << '\n';
     }
 }
```

The question is: does it possible to generate correct asm file for compilation in visual studio or it can not be used for compilation?